# Limit of an expression that includes the Lambert W function

Tags: gamma-function, lambert-w

What is $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}\ \sqrt{-(k+1)W_{-1}\left(\frac{-1}{(1+\frac{1}{k})\exp\left(\frac{1+\left(\frac{2}{k}\right)\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{k}\Gamma(k/2)}{\sqrt{2}\Gamma((k+1)/2)}\right)}{\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)}\right)}\right)-k}$ ?

Here, $\Gamma(\cdot)$ is the usual gamma function; and $W_{-1}(\cdot)$ is a real branch of the Lambert $W$ function: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1993/03/W.pdf .

I suspect, based on numerical calculations from Python code as shown below, that the answer might be close to $1.55
\approx\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$.

[image: Graph]

```
`from scipy.special import lambertw
 from scipy.special import gamma
 import math
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


 n=200
 f=np.empty(n)
 for k in np.arange(1,n+1,1):
   r1=(1+(1/k))
   r2=1+(2/k)*math.log(math.sqrt(0.5*k)*gamma(k/2)/gamma((k+1)/2))
   r3=r2/r1
   z=-1/(r1*np.exp(r3))
   w=-lambertw(z,-1)
   f[k-1]=math.sqrt((k+1)*w-k)

 fig, ax = plt.subplots()
 ax.set(xlabel='k', ylabel='f(k)')
 ax.grid()
 ax.plot(np.arange(1,n+1,1), f,'r')`
```

Comment: You are correct !

Comment: I found another (simpler) way to do it. Have a look at the update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be an excellent exercise of composition of Taylor series.

We have
$$\sqrt{-(k+1) W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{A}\right)-k}$$

Using Stirling approximation and continuing with Taylor series, we have
$$A=e+\frac{e}{k^2}-\frac{7 e}{6 k^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right)$$
$$-\frac{1}{A}=-\frac{1}{e}+\frac{1}{e k^2}-\frac{7}{6 e k^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right)$$
Now, close to $-\frac 1e$ we have
$$W_{-1}(x) \sim -1-\sqrt{2(1+ex)}\implies W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{A}\right)=-1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{k}+\frac{7}{6 \sqrt{2}
   k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)$$
$$-(k+1) W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{A}\right)-k=\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)+\frac{5}{6 \sqrt{2}
   k}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$$
$$\color{red}{\sqrt{-(k+1) W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{A}\right)-k})=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}+\frac{5}{12 \sqrt{2 \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)}
   k}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)}$$

**Edit**

Having confessed in a comment my passion for composition of Taylor expansions, I decided to go further in order to obtain much more than the limit itself.

So, we have
$$-\frac 1 A=-\frac{1}{e}+\frac{1}{e k^2}-\frac{7}{6 e k^3}+\frac{2}{3 e k^4}-\frac{1}{20 e
   k^5}-\frac{119}{360 e k^6}+\frac{391}{630 e k^7}-\frac{359}{315 e
   k^8}+\frac{55639}{45360 e k^9}+\frac{18833}{21600 e
   k^{10}}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^{11}}\right)$$ For the expansion of Lambert function, I used the expansion
$$W_{-1}(z)=\sum_{i=0}^9 b_i \,p^i \qquad \text{where} \qquad p=-\sqrt{2(1+e z)}$$ (the $b_i$'s being given [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.1628.pdf) - just below equation $(37)$).

So, now we have
$$-(k+1) W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{A}\right)-k=(1+\sqrt 2)+\frac{8+5 \sqrt{2}}{12 k}-\frac{96+99 \sqrt{2}}{864 k^2}-\frac{256-73 \sqrt{2}}{17280 k^3}+\frac{30983 \sqrt{2}-11264}{829440 k^4}+\frac{4820992+2119625 \sqrt{2}}{69672960 k^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^{6}}\right)$$ Comparing lhs and rhs shows that the relative error is smaller than $0.002$% a soon as $k >4$.

Notice that pushing the expansion drastically changes the coefficient of $\frac 1k$.

**Update**

I do not remember in which paper were given the bounds

$$-1-\sqrt{2u}-u < W_{-1}(-e^{-u-1}) < -1-\sqrt{2u}-\frac{2}{3}u$$
$$-\log (A)-\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\log (A)-1}<W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{A}\right)< -\frac{2 \log (A)}{3}-\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\log (A)-1}-\frac{1}{3}$$ Now, using
$$A=e+\frac{e}{k^2}-\frac{7 e}{6 k^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right)$$
$$(1+\sqrt2)+\frac{8+5 \sqrt{2}}{12 k}<-(k+1) W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{A}\right)-k<(1+\sqrt2)+\frac{12+5 \sqrt{2}}{12 k}$$ and then the limit using the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Impressive how yo could deal with that scary expression !

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Hi Yves ! Please don't tell my wife that, 63 years ago, I felt in love with Taylor, Padé and a few other guys (in maths !). In fact, is is simple when you take the pieces one at the time and compose series as things progress.  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Claude. I had tried Stirling, but did not apply Taylor as effectively as you did. In case you were wondering, the square-root expression is the (positive) point of intersection between the probability density functions of a standard Normal and a t-distribution with k degrees of freedom.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Since you wondered how I can deal with this kind of things, if you have time to waste, have a look at my edit ! Cheers

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: did you compute the Taylor of $W$ by hand ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust. $W_{-1}(t)$ or  $W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{A}\right)$ ? The first is known; for the second, just mental calculations as you could bet ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @YvesDaoust. We can easily find the limit using the squeeze theorem. Cheers